# How to delete an email address on StackExchange?

Tags: support, login

How do I delete one of my accounts/email addresses?

I have two and I just want one. I want to get rid of the old one.

[image]

Comment: Where exactly did you take that screenshot? You should see "remove" when doing it from your profile page.

Comment: Indeed. That seems an old layout to me...

Comment: @Pat or from the Network Profile, which let you view your logins, but not remove them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to delete an OpenID account using the *Remove* option in [your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current) under *My Logins*:

[image: sample]

(Looking at the screen shot, you are either on a site with the old layout, or you were clicking on another link than I was. Just click the link above and you should be able to update.)

On the above: it seems you are opening that dialog from the network profile, which doesn't have the option to remove yet. I created a feature request to get this implemented: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270448/245360.

Comment: The OP was probably on stackexchange.com - it doesn't have the option to remove logins.

Comment: I see. Create a feature request for that.

Comment: Indeed, the screenshot is from the network profile. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the replies. I found how to delete the email address.